# Java synchronization dilemma

Tags: java, concurrency

Suppose I have 4 objects, A, B, C and D.

- All methods on A are synchronized.
- No methods on B, C and D are synchronized.
- B is only accessed by A
- C is accessed by both A and B
- D is only accesed by B

The methods on A can be called from different threads at the same time. Is the given scenario thread-safe? That is, are all reads and writes to B, C and D visible to all threads?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So all accesses start from synchronized methods of A and all reads and writes of A,B,C, and D are done while locking on A. Then yes, that would make this arrangement thread-safe (as far as memory access is concerned, can't speak about business logic).

Note: You said "objects", not "classes", so I assume that is what you meant. If you had multiple instances of B for example, and those are shared among multiple instances of A, then this may not be thread-safe anymore. The object tree accessed by your threads must match the locks held by them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Essentially, I have a UI that runs on its own thread and calls a Controller which is synchronized. The controller is the game-loop of a game engine, so it spawns a separate thread that calls the controller's synchronized handleTick method inside a while. The problem was that saving / loading games was accessing the game data through the controller from the UI thread, not the game-loop thread. Since only one thread works at once with the game data, I wasn't sure if it's ok. Once again, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, if the whole game state is "owned" by and exclusively accessed through the controller, then you only need to synchronize the controller.